# PrimeNg table row grouping and virtual scrolling

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Row Group feature works well until I set virtual scrolling to true it stops working. I inspected the table element and found that the group header row totally disappears in virtual scrolling mode. I forked PrimeNg Stackblitz demo with rowGroupMode="subheader" [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowgroup-demo-uyktmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I would be really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: I have just encountered the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I found a couple of GitHub issues that describe the same problem. This is the most active one: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10851

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet found a solution, and they don't seem to prioritize this issue.